# setting HTTP Header for angularjs REST calls

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I'm trying to set a HTTP Header for all my REST calls with following code:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      config.headers.Authorization = '12345678';
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

I currently don't have any authorization enabled on the server.
when I leave out the line "config.headers.Authorization = '12345678';" , then the REST call works well and I get my results. In the JS console I see

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/club/1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]
```

But when I put this line in to set the Header field, then I see following request in the javascript console

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/rest/club/1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
```

Why does setting Authorization Header change my method from "GET" to "OPTIONS"? And how can I set a custom Header and my request still work?

changing it to

```
config.headers["X-Testing"] = '12345678';
```

had the same result.

EDIT:

I tried the answer, I'm setting following HTTP Headers in the server:

```
response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Header", "X-Testing");
response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Max-Age", 1728000);
```

my REST server is running on port 8080, the webserver for the html/JS on port 8000 (initially worked with file://... but moved to a separate webserver because Origin was null)

```
response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

or

```
response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
```

didn't work either.

Must I return any content in the OPTIONS response? I tried 200 OK with the same content as the GET, but I also tried 204 No Content.

2nd EDIT:

here is what firefox sends and receives for the OPTIONS method:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable CORS in your REST service. As explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), once you add a custom header, the http protocol specifies performing a preflight,

> Preflighted requests
>
> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first
>   send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the
>   other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe
>   to send.  Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data.  In particular, a request is
>   preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used
>   to send request data with a Content-Type other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>   application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted. It sets
>   custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as
>   X-PINGOTHER)

Addition to enabling CORS you also need to add a Access-Control-Allow-Headers header tag to accept your custom header (for the OPTIONS response). This is visible in the MDN Example,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 01:15:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, the OPTION response's Access-Control-Allow-Headers is missing the last "s".

Comment: it still doesn't work for me. I edited the question with further information on what I did.

Comment: You need to respond the OPTIONS as in the example I have quoted. Ensure you have the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-* tags, along with 200 OK in your response to OPTIOINS. You can keep the Content-Type as text/plain. Just the 'preflight' topic in the MDN link added in my answer

Comment: that's what I'm doing. I edited the question a 2nd time to include a screenshot of the headers Firefox sends and receives. I have CORS enabled and it works perfectly.... until I add a custom http header.

Comment: Mate, it should be Access-Control-Allow-Headers. You are missing the last "s". - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Additionally, can you also set the Content-Type in the response to text/plain. Not sure if this really affects, but it is semantically incorrect to keep that as json since you don't return any json in the response

Comment: it was the "s"! omg! thanks for lending me another pair of eyes :-)